# Prepare arguments containing quoted string in variable

Tags: bash, string, bash-expansion

In a Bash script, I call a program like this in several places:

```
numfmt --suffix=" B" --grouping 231210893
```

Where the number is different every time, but the other parameters stay the same.

I would now like to move the other parameters out of the many different calls, so they are centrally defined and can be easily changed. My attempt was like this:

```
NUMFMT='--suffix=" B" --grouping'
...
numfmt $NUMFMT 231210893
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The quote signs are removed at some point, and `numfmt` complains about an uninterpretable extra argument `B`. I tried plenty of other versions, using other quotes both in the definition and in the use of `NUMFMT`, to no avail.

How do I do this properly? And if it's not too complicated, I would also like to understand why my version doesn't work and (hopefully) another one does.

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/65304) - in particular, the section **How do I store a command in a variable?** in @Gilles answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try arrays:

```
NUMFMT=( --suffix=" B"   '--grouping' )
....
numfmt "${NUMFMT[@]}" 231210893
```

Comment: I had to remove the `"`s in the first argument, but now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that be an excellent case for an `alias`?

```
$ alias nfmtB='numfmt --suffix=" B" --grouping'
$ nfmtB 324235345656
324.235.345.656 B
```

Comment: Good idea but with a little catch: command aliases are disabled in scripts by default unless enabled with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.